# Docker Build and Push in Detail

Tags: docker, build, docker-build

Many people know, what `docker build` and `docker push` are doing in general on a high level, but what do they exactly do on a low level?

let's say we have a *Dockerfile* like this

```
FROM alpine:latest
RUN touch ~/tmp
RUN touch ~/tmp2
```

this will create the delta filesystem (only changes) for each layer in `/var/lib/docker/overlay2`.

1. layer contains a whole filesystem
2. layer contains the file `~/tmp`
3. layer contains the file `~/tmp2`

## Open questions

- What is the actual link between the layers? Is there a *json*, containing all the image info, including a sorted list of layers?
- What kind of deliverable is generated to send it to the docker registry while performing `docker push` is it a *tar.gz*, similar to `docker save`

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view:

- Each layer is transferred (only modified files add/update/deleted files instruction) to docker-registry.
- Each layer know it's parent layer.
- So when you pull down a child layer - it will pull parent layer hierarchy till the top(base layer).
- Each layer is identified by identifiers (sha256 code and not by name).
- Any change in the hierarchy will cause a different sha256 code-name for all the child image layers(even though there is no change in that layer).

Feel free to add or to suggest improvements.